# How to determine if a CSV file is unicode or not

Tags: c#, unicode

I am using C#, I have a comma delimited csv file with different strings in different languages.
My app should only open the CSV if it's unicode.

Is there an easy way to determine this in code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say "Unicode" I assume you mean UTF-8. Unicode is not an encoding and a file can't be "Unicode".

You could use a library, for example, [ude](http://code.google.com/p/ude/) is a C# library that attempts to determine what encoding a file uses. It uses the algorithm [described here](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html). It is not 100% foolproof.

Answer (score 2):

The CSV specification does not provide a way to provide metadata describing the encoding format. The specification itself uses ASCII encoding for separators. But the data tokens between separators can be anything.

You will have to read through the data itself and infer the coding type based on that.

If you are in control of the output and input, you could modify the format it for your own needs by adding your own metadata, but then it wouldn't fit the CSV file format then, if that matters in your case.

So no, there isn't an "easy" way to determine the encoding.